# error: can't copy '<dir-name>.egg-info/requires.txt': doesn't exist or not a regular file

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

When I try to install my python package, using the command `python setup.py install` I am getting this error.

I don't know what is the purpose of requires.txt and why my command is trying to find a one.

Usually when I execute this command, it will produce  `build` and `dist` directories. But now, since the above error occurs, the `dist`  is not created. And my package is not installed. Please help me to fix this up!

Comment: Move to folder that contains setup.py.

Comment: @HoseongJeon, I am running this command inside of the directory where I have the setup.py. But that command usually worked without any issue. Now when I run it for a specific package, it produces this error.

Comment: Do you have a `pkgname-pkgversion.egg_info` directory in the same dir where your `setup.py` is? If yes, remove it and rerun `python setup.py install` (no worries, the egg info dir will be recreated if necessary).

Comment: @hoefling, I ran the command after removing it as well. But still the error message is apprearing and this command is not successfully completed.

Comment: Then I suggest to create a [mcve].